# Where can I find ollydbg 2.1

Tags: ollydbg

I've seen a few references to ollydbg 2.1.0.4, but the official ollydbg website only has version 2.01. Can someone point me to a download for it? Can't find it googling either...

Comment: It may be a modded version of Olly like [this](https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.3479). AFAIK the [latest official version](http://www.ollydbg.de/version2.html) is 2.01 released September 27, 2013.

Comment: Also, if you look at the details of the ollydbg.exe v2.01, you will see that fileversion says 2.1.0.4.